# What is the difference between -f and -e in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

What is the difference between **-f** and **-e** in **shell**?

I know that

> **-e**  : To check if the file name exists
>
> **-f**  : To check if a file exists

But, what is difference among them?

---

**EDIT**:

I am looking in particular at this snippet of code:

```
if [ -e test.sh ]; then
    echo "Yes";
else
    echo "No";
fi 

if [ -f test.sh ]; then 
    echo "Yes"; 
else
    echo "No"; 
fi
```

Both print *Yes*.

Comment: Depends on _which_ shell you are talking about... `bash`, `ksh`, `sh`, `csh`, `zsh`, ...?

Comment: Hi @user2906548, can you write your whole command, please?

Comment: I'm executing the following code in a bash shell

$ `ls -lrt`
total 1.5K
-rw-r--r-- 1 e466078 fincore 3 Jun 24 13:02 **test.sh**

$ `$ if [ -e test.sh ]; then echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; fi`
**Yes**

$ `if [ -f test.sh ]; then echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; fi`
**Yes**

Comment: @arkascha I looked through the shells you listed and `-e` and `-f` are the same in all of them. Albeit their `-f` descriptions differ when referring to the `-f` option. Bash says regular file, csh calls it an ordinary file, ksh calls it a plain file.

Answer (score 5):

`-f` is like `-e` but it additionally checks that the name refers to a plain file (as opposed to a directory, socket, etc.).

See the description of `st_mode` / `S_IFMT` in [`man 2 stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) for a list of possible file types.

Comment: Thank you.
So I can conclude the following

  -e  : To check if the file/Directory/Link/Socket "NAME" exists
  -f  : To check if a file exists

Comment: @Guru24 Yes, except for the link part. AFAIK `-e` follows symlinks, so it will return false for a symlink whose target doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you. I get it